# Is it possible to get a closed-form for $\int_0^1\frac{(1-x)^{n+2k-2}}{(1+x)^{2k-1}}dx$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, definite-integrals

It is know that
$$H_n=-n\int_0^1(1-t)^{n-1}\log (t)dt,$$
see [1], where $H_n=1+1/2+\ldots+1/n$ it the **nth harmonic number**. Then I believe that can be used for $x>0$ 
$$\frac{1}{2}\log(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{2k-1}}{2k-1}\left(\frac{x-1}{1+x}\right)^{2k-1},$$
see for example [2], to show 
$$H_n=2n\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2k-1}\int_0^1\frac{(1-x)^{n+2k-2}}{(1+x)^{2k-1}}dx.$$

> **Question.** It is possible to get a closed-form for 
>   $$\int_0^1\frac{(1-x)^{n+2k-2}}{(1+x)^{2k-1}}dx?$$

If you want give a justification for previous expression for $H_n$, and know how comoute previous definite integral I am wait your answer. **Thanks in advance.**

**References:**

[1] **Furdui,** LA GACETA de la Real Sociedad Matemática Española. **Third paragraph in page 699**, see [here](http://gaceta.rsme.es/abrir.php?id=821).

[2] **Hyslop,** Infinite Series, Dover Publications (2006).

Comment: My attempt was to use **Wolfram Alpha**. I can not evaluate this integral with its definite integral calculator. A evaluation of the integral is provide us in terms of a hypergeometric function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(More of a comment, since I think you suggest you know this, but maybe this is useful to somebody else answering.)

According to Mathematica if $k,n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $2 k+n>1$,

$$I=\frac{\, _2F_1(1,2 k-1;2 k+n;-1)}{2 k+n-1}$$

Where $F$ is the [hypergeometric function on MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html).

Comment: Very thanks much for your answer @GBeau I didn't known this, I've used another integrator and the expression given as output was more difficult to evaluate.